# Create mock file instead of reading from disk for testing multer with supertest request

Tags: typescript, jestjs, multer, supertest

Hey there and thank you beforehand!

I'm trying to test multer file size and count validation with jest and supertest and I'm facing a problem with creating fake file.

The idea is to use "fake" file instead of reading a real one from disk

This is what I got so far:

```
  const formData = new jsdom.window.FormData()

  const mockFile = {
    size: 10 * 1024 * 1024,
    type: 'text/plain'
  } as Blob

  for (let i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
    formData.append('files', mockFile)
  }

  await request(app)
    .post(`/api/file-upload/`)
    // .send(mockFile)
    .attach('files', mockFile)
    // .attach('files', mockFile)
    .expect(200)
```

I tried sending file using `.send()`, but as far as I understood from docs, it's used for sending json data, so `.attach` is the right thing here. With the `.send()` I always get `req.files` undefined, and with using `.attach()` I get `TypeError: source.on is not a function`.

I'm assuming that the problem maybe with the "file" I'm trying to attach, I might mock it  wrongly. So the question is, how to mock a file and use it with supertest request instead of having real file stored on disk and using attach differently like `.attach('files', '/path-to-file/file.etc')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution for create mock file (buffer) of specific size. Credits go [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60286487/how-to-create-mocked-post-object-with-specific-size-in-mocha).

`.attach()` method works perfectly with sending buffers, and this is how you create mock buffer of specific size to test your multer file upload endpoint:

```
const buffer = Buffer.alloc(1024 * 1024 * 10, '.')
```

So working example would be:

```
const buffer = Buffer.alloc(1024 * 1024 * 10, '.')

await request(app)
  .post(`/api/file-upload/`)
  .attach('files', buffer)
  .expect(200)
```